# Making checkboxes behave like radio buttons, but one of the sections is selected by default - NSIS Components Page

Tags: installation, windows-installer, nsis

I am looking for a way so certain components behave like radio buttons, but one of the additional components is selected by default - right after starting the installer.
Unfortunately the main component gets also unselected when choosing other components, and the built-in function `.onSelChange` ignores the initially selected component.

[image: NSIS Components Page with radio selection]

```pascal
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"
OutFile "ABC.exe"
Name "ABC 1.0"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

Section "!ABC main" SEC_main
SectionEnd

Section /o "ABC expansion 1" SEC_exp1
SectionEnd

Section /o "ABC expansion 2" SEC_exp2
SectionEnd

Section /o "ABC expansion 3" SEC_exp3
SectionEnd

Section /o "ABC expansion 4" SEC_exp4
SectionEnd

Section /o "ABC expansion 5" SEC_exp5
SectionEnd

 Function .onSelChange
  !insertmacro StartRadioButtons $1
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp1}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp2}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp3}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp4}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp5}
  !insertmacro EndRadioButtons
 FunctionEnd

 Function .onInit
  SectionSetFlags ${SEC_main} 25
  SectionSetFlags ${SEC_exp3} 1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I am working on an answer. I should have seen examples that are in the NSIS directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a variable (in the code below it's `$abc_sec_exp_group`) that stores the information of the initially selected component.

```pascal
var abc_sec_exp_group

; ...

 Function .onSelChange
  !insertmacro StartRadioButtons $abc_sec_exp_group
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp1}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp2}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp3}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp4}
      !insertmacro RadioButton ${SEC_exp5}
  !insertmacro EndRadioButtons
 FunctionEnd

 Function .onInit
  SectionSetFlags ${SEC_main} 25
  SectionSetFlags ${SEC_exp3} 1
  StrCpy $abc_sec_exp_group ${SEC_exp3} ;<-------;
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Yep, NSIS contains dozens of examples (\NSIS\Examples). And one of them was "one-section.nsi" where I found the solution to this problem.